# Uvicorn won't quit with CTRL+C

Tags: docker, uvicorn, sigterm

I have a Python FastAPI app that is using uvicorn.  I have it packaged in docker container.  When I run the app (in Power Shell on my Windows 10 machine) with a command like this: `docker run -p 8080:8080 my-image-name` I get the following uvicorn startup text:

```
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I press `CTRL+C` to kill the app, nothing happens.  I always end up having to close the terminal to get it to stop.

Is this due to the fact that it's running in a docker container?

I know I can run the container in detached mode (`-d`), but sometimes I want to watch the container logs as they happen.

How can I kill the docker image and uvicorn process AND keep the terminal still running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to run the container with `--tty` and `--interactice` so that your keyboard presses are forwarded.

> -t, --tty                            Allocate a pseudo-TTY
> -i, --interactive                    Keep STDIN open even if not attached

```
docker run -ti myapp
```

Additionally, you should make sure that you don't use shell syntax for your [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), if you have one.

> The shell form prevents any CMD or run command line arguments from being used, but has the disadvantage that your ENTRYPOINT will be started as a subcommand of /bin/sh -c, which does not pass signals. This means that the executable will not be the container’s PID 1 - and will not receive Unix signals - so your executable will not receive a SIGTERM from docker stop .

```
ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

On a side note, closing the terminal, doesn't stop the container, normally. You should still see it running when doing `docker ps`.

Comment: This looked promising but for me even with `-it` for `podman run` and JSON-array form for my `ENTRYPOINT`, `uvicorn` does not exit with Ctrl+C.